# Can I nest %sysfunc-functions or achieve similar results?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following strings that are used (in different variations) as variable names:

```
Data variables;
input variable;
datalines;
Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Tag 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Farja 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Hyrbil 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Bo 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Aktiv 
Exkl_UtgUtl_Annat
;
run;
```

In order to reference related variables I need to turn variables of the type "Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg" to variables of the type "UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_Pers" and "UtgUtl_FlygSSEK_PPmedel".I try to do this in the following macro, along with other manipulations:

```
%macro imputera_saknad_utgift(variabel);

DATA IBIS3_5;
SET IBIS3_5;
if &variabel=1 and %sysfunc(cats(%qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variabel,'Exkl_','')),SSEK_Pers))=. then 
        %sysfunc(cats(%qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variabel,'Exkl_','')),SSEK_Pers))=%sysfunc(cats(%qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variabel,'Exkl_','')),SSEK_PPmedel));
```

RUN;
%mend imputera_saknad_utgift;

The documentation stated that %sysfunc can't be nested, but mentioned something about alternating
%sysfunc- and %qsysfunc-functions so I tried that. I then try to execute the code:

```
data _null_;
    set variabler2;
    call execute(cats('%imputera_saknad_utgift(',utgifter_inte_missing,')'));
run;
```

This does not seem to work however. The cats-function seems to have worked, but not the nested TRANWRD-function:

```
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.11 seconds
      cpu time            0.12 seconds
      

5         + DATA IBIS3_5; SET IBIS3_5; if Exkl_UtgUtl_Bo=1 and Exkl_UtgUtl_BoSSEK_Pers=. then    
Exkl_UtgUtl_BoSSEK_Pers=Exkl_UtgUtl_BoSSEK_PPmedel;
```

How do I make this work? The output should look something like:

```
DATA IBIS3_5; SET IBIS3_5; if Exkl_UtgUtl_Bo=1 and UtgUtl_BoSSEK_Pers=. then    
UtgUtl_BoSSEK_Pers=UtgUtl_BoSSEK_PPmedel;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but you probably should be making the transformation using SAS code, not macro code.  So write the logic to convert values in VARIABLE into the text you need to generate.  Also since it looks like you are actually parsing the strings perhaps you should do that first?  So you then have all of the individual pieces needed to construct the names needed in the code to be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your macro variable values have quote characters in them, so this code is not going to work:

```
%qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variabel,'Exkl_',''))
```

Since it is looking to replace the 7 character string `'Exkl_'` with just the two character string `''`, two quotes next to each other.

You probably meant to search for `Exkl_` instead. You probably also do not want to use %QSYSFUNC() here since that will preserve the space that TRANWRD() will insert.  You could use %SYSFUNC() to avoid having that leading space as part of the value.  Or perhaps use the TRANSTRN() function instead since that function, unlike TRANWRD(), can translate to an empty string instead of a single space.

Example:

```
439  %let variable=Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg ;
440  %put %qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variable,'Exkl_','')) ;
Exkl_UtgUtl_Flyg
441  %put %qsysfunc(TRANWRD(&variable,Exkl_,)) ;
 UtgUtl_Flyg
442  %put %sysfunc(TRANWRD(&variable,Exkl_,)) ;
UtgUtl_Flyg
443  %put %qsysfunc(TRANSTRN(&variable,Exkl_,)) ;
UtgUtl_Flyg
```